# Understanding Python List operation

Tags: python, list, sequence

I am new to python. i am learning some basic stuff. I was doing some operation on python list like this `three_lists=[]*3` when i execute this piece of code it gives me only one empty list like this`[]`. Why it is not giving me 3  empty list? some what like this `[],[],[]`

Comment: To get the effect you may be expecting, you would need to use `[[]]*3`.  However, the resulting 3 sublists would in fact all be the same list, so changing one of them would change them all, which you probably wouldn't want.  To get 3 separate sublists, you could use something like `[[] for i in range(3)]`

Answer (score 7):

It says right in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations)

> `s * n` or `n * s` equivalent to adding `s` to itself `n` times

where `s` is a sequence and `n` is an `int`. For example

```
>>> [1,2,3]*3
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

This is consistent with other sequences as well, such as `str`

```
>>> 'hello'*3
'hellohellohello'
```

If you wanted a list of 3 empty lists you could say

```
>>> [[] for _ in range(3)]
[[], [], []]
```

Answer (score 2):

it doesn't multiply lists it's multiply items inside the list
for example

```
>>> x = []*3
>>> x
[]
>>> y = [1]*3
>>> y
[1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

The rules of arithmetic(operators in programming) still apply, you can't multiple with '0' or empty value and get something different, you get the original value that you had before.